# Identify and extract locations found in a specific country / region from text using Python's locationtagger

Tags: python-3.x

I have found **locationtagger** as a python based tool which can help me extract locations from a piece of text. My problem is the locations to be extracted are expected to be from a specific location (and different regions / countries have similarly named locations). Is it possible to use **locationtagger** to identify and extract locations from a specific region / country?

Comment: Hi, why dont you show us what you have tried and what the input/expected output were? An open question like this is very hard to answer.

Comment: Hi @BijayRegmi, the text are meant to be pulled from twitter feeds so the structure may vary so when the text is pulled via the API the names of locations should be pulled by the locationtagger

Answer (score 0):

**locationtagger** library can *help to find the countries where the extracted cities, regions belong to*.

If you look for a city, locationtagger library has entity "**country_cities**" which results in a directory structure like:

```
{'country': ['city', 'city'], 'country': ['city', 'city']}.
```

You can extract the country key with a value from this directory so you will have only the cities of the country you like.
There is also similar entity for regions "**country_regions**".

For examples please look [into the documentation](https://github.com/kaushiksoni10/locationtagger).